# Using time function in Summary Report listener filename

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In JMeter (5.1.1) I have a summary report that I'm trying to save as a timestamped file. The filename value looks like the following:

```
D:\Load Tests\example.com\Results\${__time(yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss,)}_summary.csv
```

However, rather than create the file with the result of the `__time()` function e.g. `2019-07-22-10-24-03_summary.csv`, it's actually generating a filename called `${__time(yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss,)}_summary.csv`.

I've tried creating a user-defined variable called `timestamp` with the value `${__time(yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss,)}` and referencing it with `...\${timestamp}_summary.csv` but this similarly results in `$(timestamp)_summary.csv`.

I saw a [JMeter Archive post](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/Variables-in-a-listener-s-Filename-field-td516054.html) regarding a similar question to mine from 2006 where it's implied that listener filenames are resolved too early for functions and variables to be used, but I'm hoping that JMeter has been able to overcome this hurdle in the 13 years since then.

Is it possible to use variables for listener filenames in JMeter GUI and set them dynamically like the timestamp above?

If not, is there an alternative method of doing this using Groovy? Where would this be - in a setup thread JR223 sampler perhaps? I have tried this and seemingly managed to programatically change the filename, but no file was saved.

**Update with answer:**

I just needed to reverse the path delimiters from `\` to `/`.

```
D:/Load Tests/example.com/Results/${__time(yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss,)}/summary.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come across this issue and figure out that it works when you specify your path with the slash, instead of backlash.
For example:

> D:\Load
>   Tests\example.com\Results\${__time(yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss,)}_summary.csv

Doesn't work. But:

> ./Load
>   Tests/example.com/Result/${__time(yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss,)}_summary.csv

Will work.

Comment: Thanks! I came back to look at a different test and this did the trick for me! I did have the change the path to the following though - `**D:**/Load Tests/example.com/Results/${__time(yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss,)}/summary.csv` (note the drive letter). I also moved each set of results into their own directory by date which makes multiple runs easier to clean up.

Answer (score 2):

I usually don't write long answers, but you touch a bit of a sore point,

Listeners are classic example of *Can't Live with You, Can't Live Without You*

JMeter mindset is load testing (although can be used for functional tests)

Therefore, the moto/best practice is [You shouldn't use it](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

> Use CLI mode: jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl
>
> Use as few Listeners as possible; if using the -l flag as above they can all be deleted or disabled.
>
> Don't use "View Results Tree" or "View Results in Table" listeners during the load test, use them only during scripting phase to debug your scripts.

But...in the same document it suggest it for testing/debugging

> Create a simple Test Plan containing the JSR223 Sampler and Tree View Listener. Code the script in the sampler script pane, and test it by running the test.

Basically/In the end, you need to save first jtl file using `-l myresults.jtl`

And then convert it to CSV using [JMeterPluginsCMD](https://performanceengineeringsite.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/convert-jmeter-jtl-results-to-csv-or-graph-format/), example:

> ```
> JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime
> ```

Or do it the JMeter way with creating a [dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

> ```
> jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>
> ```

Comment: Thank you. This test plan is for confirming functionality changes whilst porting from one language to another. I reused an existing (load testing) plan which had no listeners and hence no problem. In this case, I have to support a number of users who can figure out the JMeter GUI but not the CLI. Creating a dashboard definitely seems like the way to go here, and I'll look into this.

Comment: I have accepted this answer now and have awarded the bounty. I had a short holiday and implemented the dashboard without any issues. The users prefer this as they can see the data in a more user-friendly fashion. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You [should not be using any Listeners in your tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/) as it violates [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)

> Use as few Listeners as possible; if using the -l flag as above they can all be deleted or disabled.

you should be [running JMeter in non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l summary.jtl
```

If you want to amend the `summary.jtl` filename to include timestamp - you can use [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/date) and [time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/time) commands combination like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l %date:~-4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%_summary.jtl
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply although I'm not sure if it's particularly feasible to switch users to using CLI over GUI purely for best practice reasons. Is it possible to use timestamps in filenames within the scope of my question (ie using the GUI)?

Comment: Okay. Well thank you but the answer as provided isn't of any use to me. For what it's worth, best practices are guidelines rather than hard and fast requirements.