# Use name of a threadGroup as part of the filename of a result time graph

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to use the name of the current thread group as part of the filename for a response time graph within that thread group.

I tried using `${__threadGroupName}` within the file path, but it´s not working.

I´m on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you will have to create different listeners under each group and write the name of each group as the filename see [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143194/using-time-function-in-summary-report-listener-filename) about dynamic file names in listeners